# Encontrar el mayor entre las coincidencias

Tags: javascript

La función va a recibir un arreglo de números en el primer parámetro, 
en el segundo parámetro viene un arreglo de números que se deben buscar
en el primer arreglo y luego se debe obtener el número más alto entre
las coincidencias, si el segundo parámetro es nulo se debe retornar
el número más alto del primer arreglo.

este es mi codigo

```
function findHighestNumber(array1 = [1,2,3], arg1 = [1,2,3]){

            }
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razon, pero puse (array1 = [1..], arg1 = [1...]) para que se dieran cuenta que parametros llegan a la funcion, ya se que piso los parametros de la funcion!

Comment: @Marcos ya edite la pregunta amigo!,

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas, donde el OP no demuestra ningún esfuerzo en resolver el problema no deberían ser bienvenidas. SOes no es un lugar para que otros resuelvan las tareas, es para preguntar dudas concretas

Comment: @SebasCarrillo, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que habías intentado para que sea reabierta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Opción 1:

Si los arreglos tienen números desordenados, entonces:

- Si el segundo arreglo es `null` entonces:

  - Ordenamos los números del primer arreglo de mayor a menor (`eg: arr1.sort((a, b) => b - a) ==> array`)
  - y devolvemos el primero (`eg: return array[0]`)
- Si el segundo arreglo no es `null` entonces:

  - Ordenamos los números del segundo arreglo de mayor a menor (`eg: arr2.sort((a, b) => b - a) ==> array`)
  - Buscamos y devolvemos el primer número que se encuentre en el primer arreglo (`return array.find(a => arr1.indexOf(a) > 0)`)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function findHighestNumber(arr1, arr2) {
  // Si arr2 es null
  if (!arr2) return arr1.sort((a, b) => b - a)[0];
  // Sino
  return arr2.sort((a, b) => b - a).find(a => arr1.indexOf(a) > 0);

}

console.log(findHighestNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]));
console.log(findHighestNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11]));
```

---

### Opción 2:

Si los arreglos tienen números ordenados de menor a mayor, entonces:

- Si el segundo arreglo es `null` entonces:

  - Devolvemos el último valor en el primer arreglo (`eg: return arr1[arr1.length - 1]`)
- Si el segundo arreglo no es `null` entonces:

  - Invertimos el orden (`eg: arr2.reverse() ==> array`)
  - Buscamos y devolvemos el primer número que se encuentre en el primer arreglo (`return array.find(a => arr1.indexOf(a) > 0)`)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function findHighestNumber(arr1, arr2) {
  // Si arr2 es null
  if (!arr2) return arr1[arr1.length - 1];
  // Sino
  return arr2.reverse().find(a => arr1.indexOf(a) > 0);

}

console.log(findHighestNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]));
console.log(findHighestNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11]));
```

Comment: Soy amante de la simpleza y la brevedad, pero tienes 3 iteraciones anidadas en ambas opciones.

Comment: Claro `.sort`, `.find` e `.indexOf`

Comment: y bueno, ¿alguien va a editar la pregunta? o la van a dejar así?

Comment: @Emeeus, estoy pensando que solo en el peor de los casos realmente se recorrerán completamente los arreglos. Cosa que en tu respuesta no pasaría, ya que deben recorrerse completamente siempre

Comment: @Marcos en realidad la solución óptima sería con dos `for` anidados, con un `break` en el segundo, pero es bastante mas largo y realmente hay que ver si se justificaría, en realidad yo tampoco usaría mi respuesta a menos que se justifique.

Comment: @Emeeus, en realidad la solución optima se daría si los números en arreglos viniesen ordenados `DESC`, entonces ahí si con 2 `for` y un `break`.

Answer (score 2):

Usando un `for` y verificando si existe y es mayor al máximo:

```js
function findHighestNumber(arr1, arr2) {
  if(!arr2){
    arr2 = arr1;
  }
  let max = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.includes(arr2[i]) && arr2[i] > max) {
      max = arr2[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(findHighestNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11]));
console.log(findHighestNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], null));
```

Para solucionar el tema del `null` como segundo parámetro podemos simplemente comparar con el mismo array.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que puedes resolverlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
function findHighestNumber(array1, arg1){
  return arg1 == null ? Math.max(...array1) : Math.max(...array1.filter(element => arg1.includes(element)))
}

console.log(findHighestNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11]));
console.log(findHighestNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], null));
```

En primer lugar, compruebo si el segundo parámetro es nulo (o `undefined`). Si lo es, devuelve el valor máximo del primer *array*.

En caso de que no lo sea, se hace el método `filter` de `Array.prototype` sobre el `array1` (recorre todos sus elementos), para obtener aquellos elementos que se encuentran contenidos en `arg1` mediante el método `includes`.

El `filter` devuelve un tercer vector, que aplicando la función `Math.max`, te devolvería el mayor.

Comment: Me gusta porque es simple y corto, pero hay tres iteraciones `.max`, `.filter` e `.includes`

Comment: Si, pero no se me ocurre de otra forma. En la respuesta anterior también se juntan 3 iteraciones. He intentado hacerlo lo más simple y corto posible :)

Comment: La respuesta es interesante, creo que se puede optimizar un poco mas, solo procura no ser tan rudo con el OP.

Comment: Llevas razón @the-breaker, ya edité, aprovechando que el OP también cambió su snippet :)

Comment: @CristianDominguez no, la mía tiene 2 iteraciones

Comment: @Emeeus cierto, perdona, se me ha ido la cabeza y he visto un segundo bucle no se dónde

Comment: @CristianDominguez de esa forma ya lo tienes en una sola linea.

Comment: Si, bastante más vistoso, aunque no soy muy amigo de los ternarios, a veces te pueden jugar una mala pasada jeje